Thread safety with std::vector (accessing and modifying different vector items with different threads)
I'm new in the world of parallel computing and doing many researches in data races and how to avoid those. The concept is quite clear to me, but I would have a question regarding the use of std::vector and modifications of their items by different threads.
So, I have this vector of vectors (l_global_vector) and pass a pointer to each element of such vector to a thread; each thread does some things and at the end swap the content of a new vector with the original one. Each thread can operates only on a single element of the vector and the vector (l_global_vector) is not modified in its size (no push back, pop, etc.). I think this is thread safe (also looking to other questions on SO), but since it involves vector of vectors I would like to ask your opinion to understand whether there could be any drawback.
So, definitive question: is the following code thread safe??
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <list>

void func(std::vector<int>* vec_ptr)
{
    std::vector<int> other_vec;
    other_vec.emplace_back(1);
    other_vec.emplace_back(20);

    vec_ptr->swap(other_vec);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> l_global_vector;
    l_global_vector.reserve(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        std::vector<int> vec_loc;
        vec_loc.emplace_back(1 + i);
        vec_loc.emplace_back(2 + i);
        vec_loc.emplace_back(3 + i);
        l_global_vector.emplace_back(vec_loc);
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(func, &l_global_vector[i]));
    }
    for (auto thread_iter = threads.begin(); thread_iter != threads.end(); thread_iter++)
    {
        thread_iter->join();
    }
}

The code runs fine, but I would like to go deeper and be sure that what I wrote is correct and there are no drawbacks (for example I read about problems with std::vector of bool). Please consider that could be also interesting to fill the vector not with int but with custom classes (that could be big).
Edit: the main assumption here is that each thread reads the content of an element of l_global_vector (the function runned by each thread takes a pointer to such element as input parameter), makes some processing, creates a new vector locally (other_vec) and then swap the original vector in the element of l_global_vector it has the pointer to with the new local vector other_vec. As far as I know and also looking at the comments, this is thread safe, but the problem could be some false sharing when many threads are doing the swap at the same time (or are writing something in the l-global_vector's element each one has the pointer to), and this could affect performance. I think it is frequent to have a vector of data (represented by l_global_vector in the sample code I posted) that must be processed by many threads (since the processing for each element takes time) and then, the result of the processing must be stored in the same vector or in a new one, this question looks at this problem.

func takes an argument but you spawn a thread without any arguments?

The libc++ implementation of std::vector::swap just swaps fields one by one. Simple but not thread-safe. One counter-example is enough: do not rely on this working, not even occasionally.

"The code runs fine" I would be surprised. The code does not actually compile on GCC, Clang and MSVC. This is mainly because of the threads.push_back(std::thread(func)); pointed out by Botje. vector is not used. std::list for threads seems sub-optimal. What about using just a vector for that? If you swap each vector in each thread separately, then there is no race condition but there is some false sharing you should care about (since it decreases performance).

Thank you all for pointing out the flaws in the post, I didn't noticed while recreating the minimal working example, now func has its argument and everything should be more clear. Posted code is working now

How can I care about false sharing?

"How can I care about false sharing?" Threads should not write in the same cache line if possible. You can avoid that with some padding or with memory alignement (align). This means wasting some memory space. It is not a problem as long as vec_ptr->swap is done once per thread (here the main bottleneck is the thread creation anyway).

Ok, thank you, it would not be abig issue for me to invest some memory to increase performance. Please consider that in the example I'm using int, but vectors could be filled with custom classes in a real project. Here func just push two ints in a vector and swaps, but it could do thousands of calculation, so thread creation should become smaller respect to to other things and swap will only happen once per thread. Basicly I'd like to modify with multiple threads alla the elements in a vector and possibily replace the original value with the new one (that's why the swap).

I could also push the result in another element of another vector (I could pass a pointer to that element to func after resizing the vector before thread creation, but I think I would incurr in false sharing the same). Could you point me to a link/example where padding or alignment is explained? I would like to learn more about that

If two threads can potentially access the same vector element concurrently and at least one of them is a writer, then you need a (mutex) lock or similar to make it thread safe.

"and the vector is not modified in its size" -- There are too many vectors floating around for "the vector" to be unambiguous. Do you mean "the outer vector" (meaning the vector that contains other vectors)?

Thank you all for the comments that help me improcing the post. I'll edit th post trying to clarify the doubts that arised. Regarding the probelm of different thread that could access the same element of the std::vector, I think the problem here is not present, the question is about having many threads that read the content of an element of a vector and modify that after processing, but it is always the same thread to read and modify the same vector elements, otherwisw for sure we need a mutex to guard the vector (or the vector's element being potentially accessed by many threads)

Post has been edited and (I hope) improved: I tried to clarify what comments pointed out. Thank you

Those threads operate on disjoint pieces of memory. Thus the code is thread safe. It does have a potential problem of threads modifying stuff too close to each other, and this might reduce performance. But is in no way unsafe.
